# Can I reliably wrap Node.js streams up synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

```
'use strict';

const stream = require('stream')

let output = ""

const s = new stream.Transform({
  transform(chunk, _encoding, callback) {
    // synchronous transformation
    callback(null, chunk);
  }
})

s.on('data', function(chunk) {
  output += chunk
})

s.write('abc')

console.log(output)
```

This prints "abc" (in Node.js v6.11.0, anyway). But is it *guaranteed* to print "abc"?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything inherently asynchronous in the implementation of `stream.Transform` that would suggest it wouldn't work as observed. However, this will (obviously) break when trying to transform data that's coming from an asynchronous source.

Comment: That's okay in this case, since I have complete control over when `write` is called.